# sqlalchemy core autoincrement integer column which is part of the unique constraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Requirement: A composite key having an auto-incremental value. How to define  the table:

```
    doc_versions = Table("doc_versions", metadata,
                         Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                         Column("doc_id", Integer,ForeignKey("docs.id")),
                         Column("version_number", Integer, default=select([
                    func.max(1, 1)])),
                         UniqueConstraint("doc_id","version_number",
                                          name="doc_version")
                         )
```

How to initialize the version number for the composite key i.e doc_id + version_number should be unique and take next sequence. I want to use sqlalchemy core only 1.0.8

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of questions about similar problems here, and the answer was always something like this (sorry for no links, just search e.g. 'sqlalchemy autoincrement composite'):

`sqlalchemy` can handle autoincrement only on integer primary keys.

It's sad, but true. But you can always query your table ordered by `doc_id` and `version_number`, get the last row, and then increment it. I'm using the same method with composite keys.